# How to disable Cross Domain Restriction

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I am providing web service which return data as JSON object. The problem is with Ajax, Ajax can't call cross domain url. Is it possible to disable it?

Comment: I found good source which explain how to use Jsonp using examples http://blog.altosresearch.com/supporting-the-jsonp-callback-protocol-with-jquery-and-java/

Answer (score 4):

You can't disable it, but you can solve the problem by accepting [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/)-requests.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONP if you can control what the other server responds. 
JSONP has to return a javascript compliant script. (var hi = {json = stuff};)

Example for the client HTML:

```
// This is our function to be called with JSON data
function showPrice(data) { 
    alert("Symbol: " + data.symbol + ", Price: " + data.price);
}
var url = “ticker.js”; // URL of the external script
// this shows dynamic script insertion
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', url);

// load the script
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

In this case the "ticket.js" url contains something like this:

```
var data = {symbol: 'Hi', price: 91.42};
```

Possibility two is you create a local (php, perl, ruby, whatever you use) script which proxies to the external JSON source.

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. The server should wrap the JSON-data in a function callback.